# Reflection a properties of type of generic list

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

i have a class like below

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  public List<T> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

and

i have a instance that above class,

```
Foo<Bar> bars = GetBars();
```

how i can get properties of Bar using reflection?

i try this

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = bars.Items.First().GetType().GetProperties();
```

but i think,its not good way,is there any better way do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var Properties = bars.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();`

Assuming you don't know the type the list will contain.

If it'll always be a `Bar` then use `typeof(Bar).GetProperties();`

Comment: yes,i dont know,type is to be everything,i tried your code and worked,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var properties = typeof(Bar).GetProperties();
```

Comment: does this not need you to know that the type is a `Bar` in advance?

Comment: It does, but the question was unclear as to if the type would be known or not when the properties were being gotten.

Comment: how can i know?,its generic.but there is a base type for that generic type.