# Casting by generic arguments

Tags: c#, types, casting

I am trying to cast an object using generic arguments in C# like
`(foo<mypara>)obj` where the `mypara` is a generic argument.

```
public class foo<T>
{
   public string name {get;set;}
    public func<T> value {get;set;}
}

var mypara = myfoo.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
```

where the value of `mypara.Name` is `"int"` or `"string"`, which is actually a string representation of the type.

But how can I get the real type of mypara?

Comment: adding some code to explain couldnt hurt

Comment: Please add a simple example demonstrating your problem, I'm sorry but I can't make any sense of what your asking as it stands.

Comment: `obj as foo<mypara>` is a better syntax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx

Comment: post the code where you are performing the cast.

Answer (score 0):

A code example would be helpful, however I think all you need is `obj.GetType()`? That is how you get the type of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if (value != null)
{
    if (value.GetType().IsGenericType == true
        && value.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Length >= 0)
    {
        IList _valuesList = null;

        if (value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString().ToLower().Contains("int"))
        {
            _valuesList = value as List<int>;
        }
        else if (value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString().ToLower().Contains("decimal"))
        {
            _valuesList = value as List<decimal>;
        }
        else if (value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString().ToLower().Contains("double"))
        {
            _valuesList = value as List<double>;
        }
        else if (value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString().ToLower().Contains("string"))
        {
            _valuesList = value as List<string>;
        }
    }
}
```

Ref:
[Get generic instance generic type using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359338/get-generic-instance-generic-type-using-reflection)
[Reflection a properties of type of generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294030/reflection-a-properties-of-type-of-generic-list)
[Reflection and generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196936/reflection-and-generic-types)

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection. GetType() on any object will get the name of the type. More reflections are necessary to make it that object type.